# Size Reading and Writing to File and conditional statements

Tags: ruby, file, size

Beginner learning Ruby. Was doing an exercise on reading and writing to file.

```
name_number = {

}

File.open("book.txt", 'a') do |file| 
  name_number.each do |name, number| 
    file.write ("- #{name} #{number}\n")
  end
  file.close
end

File.open("book.txt", "r") do |file|
  if file.size < 1
    puts "There are no people in the book."
  end

  File.open("book.txt", "r") do |file| 
    puts file.read
  end
end
```

So it outputs "There are no people in the book." when the file is empty.

SO if we add some people...

```
name_number = {
  "Bill" => 87987,
  "Kevin" => 78912
}

File.open("book.txt", 'a') do |file| 
  name_number.each do |name, number| 
    file.write ("- #{name} #{number}\n")
  end
  file.close
end
```

I was trying to figure out how to get it to say

"There is one person" for 1
and "There are some people" for anything over 1.

I thinking I need an `elsif` statement something like this, (but obviously this isn't working, but maybe you can see what I'm thinking of trying to achieve?).

```
File.open("book.txt", "r") do |file|
  if file.size < 1
    puts "There are no people in the book."
  elsif file.size == 1
    puts "There is an entry in the book."
  elsif file.size == 2
    puts "There are two entries in the book"  
  end

  File.open("book.txt", "r") do |file|
    puts file.read
  end
end
```

I'm definitely missing something. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Closing a file is important, but you don't have to close the file explicitly in this case - the block form of opening you chose takes care of that.

Comment: Thank you mentioning this! Much appreciated. Also, I figure out i could use readlines.count to solve my thing!

Comment: Note that `File.included_modules #=> [File::Constants, Enumerable, Kernel]`, so `Enumerable` methods are available for use with instances of `File`. Note also that `file.puts ("- #{name} #{number}")` (which adds a newline if one is not already present) is often used in place of `file.write ("- #{name} #{number}\n")`.

Comment: That's [IO#puts](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-i-puts). Recall `File.superclass #=> IO`, so `File` inherites `IO`'s methods. You will often see `file.m` used where `m` is an instance method of `IO`. If a file is so large that you need to read it line-by-line [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) is often the method of choice.

Comment: @realfauxreal : When you do a `file.size`, the variable holds an object of class `File` and that the method [`size`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/File.html#method-i-size) returns the file size (number of bytes in the file). I don't see how you possibly could deduce from it the number of people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain the number of lines in the file you need to read it. If possible, you want to avoid reading the file more than once.

Assuming the file is not excessively large, you could *gulp it* into an array, using [IO::readlines](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-readlines):

```
 arr = File.readlines("book.txt")     
 puts case arr.size
 when 0
    "There are no people in the book."
 when 1 
    "There is one person in the book"
 when 2
    "There are two people in the book"
 else
    "There are some entries in the book"
 end  
 puts arr
```

Alternatively, you could *gulp it* into a string, using [IO::read](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-read):

```
 str = File.read("book.txt")     
 puts case str.count("\n")
 when 0
    "There are no people in the book."
 when 1 
    "There is one person in the book"
 when 2
    "There are two people in the book"
 else
    "There are some entries in the book"
 end  
 puts str
```

If the file is so large that you need to read it one line at a time you can use [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach). This does require two passes through the file, however.

```
 puts case File.foreach("book.txt").count
 when 0
    "There are no people in the book."
 when 1 
    "There is one person in the book"
 when 2
    "There are two people in the book"
 else
    "There are some entries in the book"
 end  
 File.foreach("book.txt") { |line| puts line }
```

Answer (score 1):

file.size gives you the number of bytes. You probably want [file.readlines](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/IO.html#method-i-readlines).size

Answer (score 0):

I found if I used **.count** with **readlines** I was able to solve my problem!

updated code

```
File.open("book.txt", "r") do |file|
  number = file.readlines.count
    if number < 1
      puts "There are no people in the book."
    elsif number == 1 
      puts "There is one person in the book"
      File.open("book.txt", "r") do |file| 
        puts file.read
      end
    elsif number == 2
      puts "There are two people in the book."
      File.open("book.txt", "r") do |file| 
        puts file.read
      end
    elsif number >= 3
      puts "There are some entries in the book."  
      File.open("book.txt", "r") do |file| 
        puts file.read
      end
    end
  end
```